# execute hive with python code

Tags: python, sql, hive

I have recently started python and i have a requirement of taking a query as a argument in a python script and executing it on hive and then fetching the result. As I am new to all this, I need an answer with basic clarity.

Answer (score 1):

you can use module [PyHive](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyHive)

```
pip install pyhive[hive]
```